# Azure Logic Apps Gmail and Twitter

Tags: azure, twitter, gmail, azure-logic-apps

I need user's email address who tweets with specific Hashtag(#),
and email that user with the Twitter name and some content,
I don't know how to get the email of the twitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found discussion on this,
Not a solution but it might help

A Question was asked to Adrian Hall - Sr. Program Manager at Microsoft.

**His Answer:**

> It’s really a matter of figuring out the right incantation to get Twitters OAuth provider to return the email address. Since Twitter uses a username instead of an email address as an identifier, you probably have to ask for **additional claims**. I’m writing about auth this week, so I’ll take a look at the problem and write a blog post about it if/when I figure it out.

**Link:**
[ShellMonger.com](https://shellmonger.com/sample-page/)